# AOL reader authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, rss, aol

I'm checking AOL Reader's API (http://reader.aol.com/api) which looks pretty good, but I'm missing one information: Where to start to authenticaticate with AOL? How can I get a AOL authentication token?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also interested in this, apparently you need to create an account as a dev on AOL reader, but I don't see where you can create one

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact AOL support to get approved as a dev

Here are the instructions to do that:

http://help.reader.aol.com/forums/214274-general-discussion/suggestions/4149989-how-i-get-aol-authentication-token

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they haven't enable it yet.

Check this out:
http://api.screenname.aol.com/reader/user/info